# Visual Studio 2012 vstest: run tests that do not belong to a category

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2012, vstesthost

Is it possible to run all tests that **do not** belong to a category from the command line? From the documentation, I know that I can run all tests that are a member of a category doing something like:

> vstest.console.exe myTestProject.dll /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory="Nightly"

What I want to do is assign a few test methods to a test category and then run those tests in one run. I then want to run the remainder of the tests in a separate test run (which is where my current problem lies). I have over 1000 tests, so I am hoping that I don't have to do a search and replace on all the TestMethod attributes to add a 'basic' category. I also don't want to have to separate the tests out into different projects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, I got the tumbleweed badge for this question, so I guess nobody is interested. In case someone does stumble onto the same problem, I found that I could just use the != operator. The Microsoft documentation is very lean, but I found the info I needed in [MSDN blog "Running selective unit tests in VS 2012 RC using TestCaseFilter"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/07/23/running-selective-unit-tests-in-vs-2012-rc-using-testcasefilter.aspx).

So, the answer is:

```
vstest.console.exe myTestProject.dll /TestCaseFilter:TestCategory!="Nightly"
```

**Update:** As pointed out by Rob Bos below. The docs now have:

`dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName!=MSTestNamespace.UnitTestClass1.TestMethod1`

> Runs all tests except MSTestNamespace.UnitTestClass1.TestMethod1

Source [Running selective unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests) on MSDN.

Comment: I agree that there's not enough documentation on this. If you have multiple TestCategories, you can filter on multiple expressions: `"TestCategory!=Other&TestCategory!=Another&TestCategory!=That"`

Comment: Thank you for the solution! :) This is still missing in the documentation.

Comment: The docs have been improved! This works in VsTest as well: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests)